# Alternative for scrollTo in react-native ScrollView

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to implement anchor scrolling in react-native.
I am able to do so by using ScrollView and scrollTo.

According to [react-native's documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview#scrollto) scrollTo method should not be used in ScrollView(deprecated).

Is there any alternative for the scrollTo method to achieve similar functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, `scrollTo` is not really deprecated.

But `scrollTo(([y]: number), object, ([x]: number), ([animated]: boolean))` is.

Thus you should just use `scrollTo({x: 0, y: 0, animated: true})` with a single object as parameter.

It is stated in the link you provided: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview#scrollto:

> The weird function signature is due to the fact that, for
>   historical reasons, the function also accepts separate arguments as an
>   alternative to the options object. This is deprecated due to ambiguity
>   (y before x), and SHOULD NOT BE USED.

Perhaps it is misleading but it's only the alternative with separate arguments which is deprecated.